# Is there a way to set Remaining Work to be 0 when a task is done on azure devops?

Tags: azure-devops

We use azure devops to manage our sprint and burn down chart to show how we are doing. One practical issue is that when we close a story, we forget to close the tasks in it. Then when we close the task, we forget to set remaining work to be 0, as a result the burn down chart can't reflect this.

Is there a way that when we close the story or set the task to done, the remain work can be set to 0 automatically?

I found some posts talking about TFS Automation (e.g., [this link](https://tfsaggregator.github.io/docs/v2/using/examples/log-time-synch/)), in which you can set up some rules to set remaining work to 0, but not sure if it fits for azure devops?

Answer (score 2):

You can create rule for you template.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/settings/work/rule-reference?view=azure-devops&tabs=inheritance
[image]
[image]